# Smoother way to Serialize the Objects from muliple Source and different Schema?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, serialization, mfc, visual-c++-6

I am trying to make up a Serialization for my object which can be from a multiple source, say Source 1 and Source 2, the schema handling is pretty screwed up in both. So I am trying to handle in a smooth Serialization.

```
void CSerFoo::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    try
    {
        //ar.Flush();
        SerializeEx(ar); // For the Serialization of the Good Ones, from the point now on
    }
    catch(...) // If the Object cannot be Serialized using the above Method try the Next way to decode
    {
        try
        {
            //ar.Flush();
            SpecialSerialize1(ar); // For the Serialization of the Objects from the Source 1, actually code from the Source 1
        }
        catch(...) // If the Object cannot be Serialized using the above Method try the Last way to decode
        {
            try
            {
                //ar.Flush();
                SpecialSerialize2(ar); // For the Serialization of the Objects from the Source 2, actually code from the Source 2
            }
            catch(...)
            {
                // No way
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

This is the Serialization Code from Source 1

```
// From Source 1
IMPLEMENT_SERIAL( CSerFoo, CObject, VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 3)
void CSerFoo::Serialize(CArchive& ar) // This will be the Consolidated CSerFoo's SpecialSerialize1
{
    UINT uiSchema = ar.GetObjectSchema();
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << m_sName;                          
        ar << m_sDesc;
        ar << m_String1;

        ar << m_fValue1;
        ar << m_fValue2;

        ar << m_iValue1;
        ar << m_iValue2;

        ar << m_String2;
        ar << m_String3;

    }
    else
    {
        ar >> m_sName;                          
        ar >> m_sDesc;
        ar >> m_String1;

        if(uischema > 0)// Added in VERSION_SCHEMA 1
        {
            ar >> m_fValue1;
            ar >> m_fValue2;
        }

        if(uischema > 1) // Added in VERSION_SCHEMA 2
        {
            ar >> m_iValue1;
            ar >> m_iValue2;
            ar >> m_String4;
        }

        if(uischema > 2) // Added in VERSION_SCHEMA 3
        {
            ar >> m_String2;
            ar >> m_String3;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Serialization Code from Source 2

```
// From Source 2
IMPLEMENT_SERIAL( CSerFoo, CObject, VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 3)
void CSerFoo::Serialize(CArchive& ar) // This will be the Consolidated CSerFoo's SpecialSerialize2
{
    UINT uiSchema = ar.GetObjectSchema();
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        ar << m_sName;                          
        ar << m_sDesc;
        ar << m_String1;

        ar << m_fValue1;

        ar << m_fValue2;
        ar << m_iValue1;
        ar << m_iValue2;

        ar << m_iValue3;
        ar << m_String2;
        ar << m_String3;

    }
    else
    {
        ar >> m_sName;                          
        ar >> m_sDesc;
        ar >> m_String1;

        if(uischema > 0)// Added in VERSION_SCHEMA 1
        {
            ar >> m_fValue1;

        }

        if(uischema > 1) // Added in VERSION_SCHEMA 2
        {
            ar >> m_fValue2;
            ar >> m_iValue1;
            ar >> m_iValue2;
        }

        if(uischema > 2) // Added in VERSION_SCHEMA 3
        {
            ar >> m_iValue3;
            ar >> m_String2;
            ar >> m_String3;
        }
    }
    // m_String4 is not there in the Source 2
}
```

Now the consolidated `CSerFoo`(from now on) have all the Fields from both the Sources and there we want the newer Serialization for the same object of CSerFoo. We cannot compromise on creating another class.

**The Problem what I face is, on subsequent calls of Serialization the cursor(CArchive::m_lpBufCur) is moved and hence the next try of Serialize failing.**

Is there a way to achieve this?

Am I missing anything?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Without knowing what the SerializeEx and SpecialSerializeX do, it is hard to say anything about this.

Comment: It is all just serialization of the int's, float's and string's in a sequence. The Sequence and number of fields may differ in each serialization, thats what the problem is.

Comment: There is no problem, when using versionable schemas, and versionable schemas are the standard solution to the issue you invented. See [CArchive::GetObjectSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkbc2za4.aspx) for a short introduction, as well as [TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32wxt301.aspx) for the details. At any rate, the question, as asked, cannot be answered. Please provide a [mcve] so that we have a common base.

Comment: There is no clean way to fix the mess you programmed yourself into. (I don't even know how you convinced the linker to accept two objects with the same name `CSerFoo`.) You'd have to rewrite the entire serialization infrastructure to get back into business. And even then, it's fairly involved to work around your violation of the single definition rule. And since MFC stores the class names into the serialized stream, the SDR applies to MFC's serialized streams as well. You should have hired a developer...

Comment: I'm not recommending this, but there's a [CFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60fh2b6f.aspx) in every `CArchive` ([CArchive::GetFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d2s70f0.aspx)). The `CFile` has [GetPosition()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b2hf282.aspx) and [Seek()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ccz0x.aspx) members. You need to fix your exception handling, too. MFC exceptions aren't automatically cleaned up (see [Exception Handling in MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t078xe4f.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable I don't have the All the Serializations into one File and naming under CSerFoo. Edited for the better understanding.

Comment: That didn't help to make anything clearer. So you have different files, or at least different `CArchive` contexts? How about you asked about the problem you are really trying to solve instead of your (proposed) solution.

Comment: @IInspectable, there are two Source of CSerFoo(from different flavors of Application) and are stored in the File or DB. Now I am trying to consolidate both the flavors into one, there this Serialization of the CSerFoo is the problem. So I need a centralized Serialization for all, Consolidated, From Flavor 1 and Flavor 2, in the newer consolidated one. This gonna stay forever.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions seems to be the wrong way to solve this if you do not have a [strong exepction safety guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) .

So you can implement the functions so they adhere it (only using local offsets in the functions not like one inside of the CArchive object or copy it inside the function)

But also it seems like exceptions are abused as control structures here. You should maybe consider using exceptions only on "exceptional" circumstances and have some functions like

```
if(isFormat1Convertible(ar))
{
    SerializeEx(ar);
}
else if(isFormat2Convertible(ar))
{
    SpecialSerialize1(ar);
}
...
```

This seems to me like cleaner code and does not "abuse" exceptions.

Comment: A crude kludge, written by someone who doesn't understand [Serialization in MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bz744w8.aspx). As for exceptions, they should be thrown when a function fails to deliver its promise. Whether that is fatal (or *"exceptional"*) is for the client code to decide. In general, code that throws an exception hardly ever knows, whether this failure is fatal in context.

Comment: Yes, this is not be the "MFC" way, but I prefer programming "into" a language/framework instead of "in" a language (see "Code Complete" Chapter 4 for some explanation on this). And there are several discussions on the internet / books which see this usage of exceptions in the OP as "code smell" (and OP has some issues with it else the post would not exist). I haven't used MFC for a while but as I see from the docu there is a thing called "VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA". Maybe this can be used to chose the right format instead of exceptions (or other methods but that depends on the circumstances).

Comment: You have to know a framework to make an educated decision, whether you want to program in it or into it. Advice from *Code Complete* comes with a rationale. Your lack of insight deprives you of applying it. Besides, you cannot program into MFC's serialization, unless you change it, and break the rules, and then come here to ask for help with the mess you wound up with.

Comment: Yeah you are right there. It was mostly a suggestion on a different design. For creating a "strong exception safety" merely reopening the file and having a new CArchive Object for each call would be enough (which is kind of hinted at in the first part of my answer). Or if it comes from another buffer, copy the buffer before you load it into a CArchive.  Is not really efficient though.